# Sudden drop in meta reputation doesn't appear in profile

Tags: support, reputation, meta, reputation-history

This morning, I had a reputation of 13,010 here on MSO. All of the sudden, my reputation dropped by 280 points to its current state of 12,730.

I suppose I lost the rep fairly and squarely (`/reputation` agrees with the current value), but [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123319) left me with the impression that any action that results in a rep change should show up in my profile.

However, there are no rep changes registered for today (and yes, I have *show removed posts* is checked). Does this mean that there's a bug somewhere or are there any action that don't show up on the profile page (e.g., hard deletions)?

Comment: Huh. I do see a reputation recalculation performed today on your account that took you from 13010 to 12730, but I don't see what would have caused the drop. You had one self-deleted answer recently, but it had no votes on it. I also don't see any invalidated votes from a misfire of the serial voting script. Odd.

Comment: Reputation recalcs (from that page) don't cause new events to appear in your history; so if it caught something far back in your timeline, it's just gone now. The recalc page is obsolete, and if you read the comments in that question (somewhere), they do say it will be going away. Maybe they just don't care whether it's there or not. The button should be disabled though. I thought someone said it doesn't even use the same methods to check your reputation as the current, automated system.

Comment: @animuson: I didn't trigger a recalc manually. I visited `/reputation` as part of the troubleshooting process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two posts were deleted:

- 170 rep: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144479/the-stone-of-david/144481#144481
- 110 rep: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145225/privacy-problem-in-the-stack-exchange-chat/145228#145228

But due to a code bug at the time of those deletions, you were not auto-recalced at the time of deletion.  However when [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151695/is-bountify-co-a-legit-site-or-something-to-be-concerned-about/151700#151700) was deleted a recalc *was* triggered, catching you up to actual rep.

Comment: FWIW, the same thing happened to me on another deleted question.